# Access Inbox items from the API?

Tags: asana

Is there a way to access the items in a workspace's inbox via the API? I'm primarily interested in the unread count, but could make good use out of any unhidden items as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you can't do this with a simple API call.

You *might* be able to do it by pulling down all projects, and then pulling down all the tasks for each project, storing that in a local database, and then search for tasks with assignee_status set to "inbox" (https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks). But that is probably not the answer you want!

Comment: Heh. Yeah, that's a little more... expensive than I was hoping for. Any chance of getting this added as a feature?

Comment: (I work at Asana.) A changelog / webhooks system is at the top of our list of big API features to build. Sadly, I can't say how far off it is.

Comment: @Greg S: Any news for this API call/function? This would be good for an information booth in the coffee corner, etc.

Comment: We've recently actually started work on it, so it's in the prototype phase now. There will be news on http://developer.asana.com/api-updates/ when we've got more to show.

Comment: @GregS Still no update about this feature? Still no inbox-related feature in API updates :/

Comment: The change events system is back under development and actually approaching launch! We had to deprioritize it in order to support our new iOS mobile app launch, but it's back in the works. Just a point of clarification: it will help you read changes in the system, but is not an API for a user's Inbox itself (which, reading your question, may be what you're after.) An Inbox API is also on the roadmap, but I unfortunately can't say when. Likely not in the next 3 months, but possibly in the next 6, I'm happy to give you an update on that if you ping me again later.

Comment: I have an application that does exactly what you describe... thanks for reminding me that they have the state of inbox. perfect, we already have that database on our server. Now I can nudge people to go there from our dashboard.

Comment: @adudley Can you please explain how your system is working?
@GregS `it will help to read changes in the system`. Can you please point me to explanation for this ? Also is api to access inbox is out yet or not ?

Comment: @shivams I don't quite get what you mean. But we really do copy every single task into our own database. I was looking for a way to put on our dashboard 'hey, you have X items in your inbox on asana, go see them, click here'