# Asana api to get content from inbox

Tags: asana, asana-api

I want to get updates from `asana inbox` directly using `asana api`.

Is there any way this can be done using api as i am unable to find anything in api documentation. If there is anything that i might have missed in api please point me to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have an endpoint for the inbox.  As was discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718885/6496241), you may be able to get this by grabbing every task across all projects into a local database.  You would then need to search for tasks where `assignee_status` is set to `inbox`.